# What does DFA that accepts at least 1 a or at least 1 b mean?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

What are the language accepted by this DFA?

The truth table of OR-:

[image]

But I am unable to deduct what this dfa will accept?
Say-:
P=at least 1 a
Q=at least 1 b

So DFA should accept both ab. Or in another case it could accept a and in another case it could accept  b? Is this the interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

This will accept any word containing $a$ or $b$. There's a simpler way of describing the set of all words accepted by the FA, by the way. Can you see it?